AWS S3 Pixel Tracking for Email Opens Not Logging Image Access
Question:
I’m working on tracking email opens using a pixel image hosted on AWS S3. Here’s the setup I’ve implemented:

Bucket 1 (email-tracking-pixel-ssp): Contains the pixel image (S logo white circle 200x200.png).
Bucket 2 (email-open-logging): Intended to log when the image is accessed/opened via server access logging.

Both buckets are public, and I’ve set bucket policies to allow access. The pixel image is being embedded in emails using the following URL structure:
https://email-tracking-pixel-ssp.s3.amazonaws.com/S%20logo%20white%20circle%20200x200.png
The image loads correctly when the email is opened, but no access logs are being generated in email-open-logging.
How can I ensure that each access of the pixel image is logged in the email-open-logging bucket?
Am I missing any specific configuration in AWS that would enable this?
What I Tried:
Bucket Configuration: Created two S3 buckets—one for the pixel image and one for logging access.
Access Logging: Enabled server access logging on the email-tracking-pixel-ssp bucket and directed the logs to the email-open-logging bucket.
Bucket Policies: Applied public access policies to both buckets to ensure the image can be accessed by anyone who opens the email.
What I Expected:
When an email recipient opens the email and the pixel image loads, I expected that an access log entry would be generated in the email-open-logging bucket.
What Actually Happened:
The image loads as expected when the email is opened, but there are no access logs being generated in the logging bucket. All I get are internal logs nothing that notes a Getobject was created.

Server access logs aren't guaranteed to be complete or near-real time:

Best-effort server log delivery
Server access log records are delivered on a best-effort basis. Most requests for a bucket that is properly configured for logging result in a delivered log record. Most log records are delivered within a few hours of the time that they are recorded, but they can be delivered more frequently.
The completeness and timeliness of server logging is not guaranteed. The log record for a particular request might be delivered long after the request was actually processed, or it might not be delivered at all. It is possible that you might even see a duplication of a log record. The purpose of server logs is to give you an idea of the nature of traffic against your bucket. Although log records are rarely lost or duplicated, be aware that server logging is not meant to be a complete accounting of all requests.
Source: AWS Docs - Logging requests with server access logging

It may take a couple of hours until the access logs show up, so you may just need some patience. As the docs outline, they may also not show up at all, so depending on your requirements using S3 as the backend for your pixel tracking may not work.
